# How to return a file in web application using Tapestry

Tags: java, html, tapestry

I am working on a web application of Data Compression Library. What it does is that it takes an Input file and downloads it on localhost for processing. Downloading is done by using the UploadedFile service of tapestry. After taking this file, a C++ executable is invoked when the form is submitted in the browser. The output of the C++ program is the compressed file that is generated in the same directory as of the downloaded original file. Now what I have to do is, to make the compressed file available for download for the user. I am redirecting the user to another page after the form is filled.

The same goes for decompression, i.e, a form is filled in which file is selected and the file is downloaded to localhost. Decompression is performed via the C++ program and file is generated. User is redirected to another page.

How do I make this file available for download? It should be like a button is displayed and when the user clicks on it, the Save File as pop up should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

On Java side, just implement an event handler (maybe associated to click events on the download button displayed) returning an instance of the `org.apache.tapestry5.StreamResponse` interface.

You can find some examples on Tapestry's wiki: https://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToStreamAnExistingBinaryFile.